# IoT Dashboard for Raspberry Pi

Tags: microsoft-windows-iot

I am currently experimenting with IoT using a Raspberry pi 3 and Windows IoT core. I have orded the sensors but in the meantime I am simulating them by using hard codes values. This is all for a project that we are designing. I am looking for a dashboard where I can pass the data from the pi through an API to a dashboard using C#. The dashboard must be able to map multiple pi locations on a map and be able to send alerts when a pi gets disconnected. This is a little customized but I am pretty sure there is something available and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does it have to be in c#?

Comment: Simple enough to code. Each Pi sends a "heartbeat" to a central server every X seconds/minutes. When no heartbeat is received update the map; when a heartbeat is received from a previously dead Pi, update the map. Personally, I would make this browser based, rather than desktop app (and use LeafletJS & Open Street Map, rather than Google Maps). If it must be C#, then ask us on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for a C# mapping library.  Great question (+1 & starred as favo(u)rite).

Comment: @mawg thank you so much for the response. I have managed to find an Azure solution that perfectly fits my needs. The solution is called IoT Central. You should check it out.